# Is depleting batteries of MacBook Pro 2018 still a thing in 2018?

Tags: battery

I was looking for battery related applications in Brew and found [Battery Guardian](https://www.dssw.co.uk/batteryguardian/) which refers to an [Apple page from 2011](https://web.archive.org/web/20110521104819/http://www.apple.com/batteries/notebooks.html) as justification why this application matters. Referring an old page as justification it's a bit suspicious for me. Depleting battery frequently - the page says monthly is a good cadence - still something I have to pay attention to?